# Dell Precision T3600 doesn't start BIOS when inserting a HDD WD40EZRZ (4 TB, SATA)

Tags: hard-drive, dell-precision

**Intention**: I want to put a 4 TB WD WD40EZRZ HDD (3,5") into my Dell Precision T3600.

**State before and what IS working**: I've got a Dell Precision T3600 with a 256 GB SSD and a 1 TB WD HDD (2,5") which is working fine.

Now I want to upgrade to a larger 4 TB WD WD40EZRZ HDD (3,5"). When attached via a USB adapter, the WD40EZRZ is also working fine. The PC found it and I can use all the 4 TB of it.

Because of some 2,x TB frontier I partitioned it using GTP.

**Problem**: When I attach the WD40EZRZ to one of the SATA cables (with or without unplugging both other SSD/HDD does not change the behavior) then the PC stops booting at the startup screen and I can't even enter the BIOS.

**Details**: The PC shows the Dell logo and a blue loading bar (that stucks in the middle) and it shows the BIOS version A18. A18 is the newest version at the Dell website available.

When I press F12 in this state then the message at top right says that the PC will go to BIOS but that does not happen. Not even after some minutes.

When I press F2 at startup then the PC shows (a) the Dell logo and the loading bar and then (b) a black screen with a blinking cursor and then (c) only a black screen. There is no change even when I wait for some minutes.

**What I tried** (one change at a time, but not strictly in this order):

- Activating UEFI (instead of Legacy).
- Deactivating SMART
- Deactivating TPM Security
- Disabling Chassis Intrusion
- Using other SATA connectors (HDD0, HDD1, SATA1); at SATA0 there is the DVD drive
- Booting successfully with another (smaller) HDD (WD WD2500AAJS 250GB) in this configuration and installing Debian from a CD to that HDD.

**Question**: How can I get that 4 TB WD WD40EZRZ HDD to work within the Dell Precision T3600 as internal drive?

Comment: Please try to run that drive in a different computer. If that fails you might haven a short circuit on your drive.

Comment: When attached via an USB-SATA adapter, the WD40EZRZ is working fine. So I guess it's not a short circuit, right?

Comment: Yes. Is your operating system GPT compatible? What is it's name? Disconnect the other HDD and maybe the SSD to minimize the load on your power supply.

Comment: With the other HDD and SSD and even the DVD drive disconnected from power supply (and disconnected from the SATA data cables) the result is still the same: the computer stops the BIOS loading bar exactly in the middle and doesn't do anything after that. The screen looks similar to this: https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTAxMVgxNDEw/z/UyYAAOSwayxh5~sv/$_59.JPG (but with revision A18 in my case and I don't have an OptiPlex). I tried every of the three power connectors with the WD40EZRZ.

Comment: To the operating system: there is no operating system at the 4 TB WD40EZRZ because the computer does not boot far enough to start the operating system or a boot CD/DVD. With the same BIOS configuration but another (smaller than 4 TB) HDD (WD2500AAJS) the computer runs far enough to start a boot CD and I was able to install a Debian 11 on that WD2500AAJS. But with the WD40EZRZ connected the computer stops before booting an operating system from the boot CD/DVD. If the WD2500AAJS with installed Debian AND the WD40EZRZ are connected, the computer still just starts to 50% of the BIOS loading bar.

Comment: The WD2500AAJS I also partitioned with GPT and I was able to install the Debian 11 onto it. So it seems to be GPT compatible.